# how to make centre of the Google map to the bottom centre of the iPhone screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-maps

I am developing an iPhone app; I am rotating the map with respect to magnetic heading. When I rotate mobile the map rotates with respect to centre point of the screen as shown in image(point 1), 
I want to bring centre point to the bottom centre of the (in image point 2) how to implement it in objective-C ?

[image: points are displayed in image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have to use UIEdgeInsets (mapView padding)

```
UIEdgeInsets mapInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(400.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); mapView.padding = mapInsets;
```